# How correctly make TF-IDF vectors of sentences in Apache Spark with Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, tf-idf

I have this code,

```
public class TfIdfExample {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            JavaSparkContext sc = SparkSingleton.getContext();
            SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "spark-warehouse")
                    .getOrCreate();
            JavaRDD<List<String>> documents = sc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(
                    Arrays.asList("this is a sentence".split(" ")),
                    Arrays.asList("this is another sentence".split(" ")),
                    Arrays.asList("this is still a sentence".split(" "))), 2);


            HashingTF hashingTF = new HashingTF();
            documents.cache();
            JavaRDD<Vector> featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(documents);
            // alternatively, CountVectorizer can also be used to get term frequency vectors

            IDF idf = new IDF();
            IDFModel idfModel = idf.fit(featurizedData);

            featurizedData.cache();

            JavaRDD<Vector> tfidfs = idfModel.transform(featurizedData);
            System.out.println(tfidfs.collect());
            KMeansProcessor kMeansProcessor = new KMeansProcessor();
            JavaPairRDD<Vector,Integer> result = kMeansProcessor.Process(tfidfs);
            result.collect().forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }
```

I need get Vectors for k-means, but I getting odd Vectors

```
[(1048576,[489554,540177,736740,894973],[0.28768207245178085,0.0,0.0,0.0]),
     (1048576,[455491,540177,736740,894973],[0.6931471805599453,0.0,0.0,0.0]),
     (1048576,[489554,540177,560488,736740,894973],[0.28768207245178085,0.0,0.6931471805599453,0.0,0.0])]
```

after k-means work I getting it

```
((1048576,[489554,540177,736740,894973],[0.28768207245178085,0.0,0.0,0.0]),1)
((1048576,[489554,540177,736740,894973],[0.28768207245178085,0.0,0.0,0.0]),0)
((1048576,[489554,540177,736740,894973],[0.28768207245178085,0.0,0.0,0.0]),1)
((1048576,[455491,540177,736740,894973],[0.6931471805599453,0.0,0.0,0.0]),1)
((1048576,[489554,540177,560488,736740,894973],[0.28768207245178085,0.0,0.6931471805599453,0.0,0.0]),1)
((1048576,[455491,540177,736740,894973],[0.6931471805599453,0.0,0.0,0.0]),0)
((1048576,[455491,540177,736740,894973],[0.6931471805599453,0.0,0.0,0.0]),1)
((1048576,[489554,540177,560488,736740,894973],[0.28768207245178085,0.0,0.6931471805599453,0.0,0.0]),0)
((1048576,[489554,540177,560488,736740,894973],[0.28768207245178085,0.0,0.6931471805599453,0.0,0.0]),1)
```

But I think it work not correctly, because tf-idf must have another view.
I think `mllib`  have ready methods for this, but I tested documentation examples and don't receive what I need. Custom solution for Spark I have not found. May be somebody work with it and give me answer what I doing wrong? May be I am not correctly use mllib functional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are getting after TF-IDF is a [SparseVector](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/SparseVector.html).

To understand the values better, let me start with TF vectors:

```
(1048576,[489554,540177,736740,894973],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])
(1048576,[455491,540177,736740,894973],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])
(1048576,[489554,540177,560488,736740,894973],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])
```

For instance, TF vector corresponding to the first sentence is a `1048576` (`= 2^20`) component vector, with 4 non-zero values corresponding to indices the `489554,540177,736740` and `894973`, all other values are zeros and therefore not stored in the sparse vector representation.

The dimensionality of the feature vectors is equal to the number of buckets you hash into: `1048576 = 2^20` buckets in your case.

For a corpus of this size, you should consider reducing the number of buckets:

```
HashingTF hashingTF = new HashingTF(32);
```

powers of 2 are recommended to minimize number of hash collisions.

Next, you apply IDF weights:

```
(1048576,[489554,540177,736740,894973],[0.28768207245178085,0.0,0.0,0.0])
(1048576,[455491,540177,736740,894973],[0.6931471805599453,0.0,0.0,0.0])
(1048576,[489554,540177,560488,736740,894973],[0.28768207245178085,0.0,0.6931471805599453,0.0,0.0])
```

If we look at the first sentence again, we got 3 zeros - which is expected, since the terms "this", "is", and "sentence" appear in every document of the corpus, so [by definition of IDF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/mllib-feature-extraction.html#tf-idf) will be equal to zero.

Why do the zero values still in the (*sparse*) vector? Because in the current implementation, [the size of the vector is kept the same](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/feature/IDF.scala#L210) and only the values are multiplied by IDF.

Comment: Thank you, but what u mean _I am assuming the printout was truncated_, I am copy paste all from console. And because I think that tf-idf return me no true vectors. I make `new HashingTF(32);`  and ID's in first tuple become smaller. But I not understand why in some values in second tuple I get 0.0

Comment: I ran your example, and indeed these values should be equal to zero. I have added more details/links to the explanation - let me know if it helps.

Comment: One question, `(1048576,[489554,540177,736740,894973],[0.28768207245178085,0.0,0.0,0.0])` in this vector `[0.28768207245178085,0.0,0.0,0.0]` it tf-idf after apply IDF to TF?

Comment: The SparseVector is given by `(size, indices, values)`, so the actual components of the vector are in this list `[0.28768207245178085,0.0,0.0,0.0]`. This is after IDF, yes

Comment: But how fast get vector with `values`?

Comment: I try use toDense, but I get many 0.0 in dense vector. I think it this is something that should be. Thank you again.